# Firebase Query Chaining?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How would a Query, where I want to check if a Person Already Created a (not Running)Game look like?
I know how to make a simple Query, but it isn't possible to chain Query's right?

**const-ID = "some id"**

```
if(creator.displayName == const-ID && state == 1) return true
else return false
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont need to nest the creator inside the game, instead displayName and uid should be direct childs of the game.

Then you still have the problem because you want 2 search criteria. Sadly you cant do that in Firebase, yet. But what you can do is to generate another node inside the game called "state_uid". And then, query like child("games").orderByChild("state_uid").equalsTo("1_"+uid);

Look at this Firebase video https://youtu.be/sKFLI5FOOHs

Comment: hello, i already safed the whole playlist hehe<br> after watching this video from an google dev. <br> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8wF-mKMsynE <br> i nested the information just like he did, but will change that soon thanks!

Comment: if i do soemthing like this: https://pastebin.com/raw/mT9v76Lf its printing 1 and 2 and the function isnt working what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Well, you the nesting rule is, nest as less as you can and don't transfer unnecesary data, in this case it could be acceptable.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the query. The once method is a promise therefore it will resolve asynchronously. That mean any code below will also be executed since the promise is being processed in "paralel".